# PHP: File_put_content doesn't create the file

Tags: php, file-put-contents

this is really strange, this php code worked well for a long time

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $arr = explode(' ',trim($data));
  $file =  $arr[0];
  $my_file = "bet_shared/".$file;
  $sharing_bet = strstr($data," ");
  file_put_contents($my_file, $sharing_bet);
}
else
{
    var_export($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
}
?>
```

Now the method file_put_contents($my_file, $sharing_bet) doesn't create the file in bet_shared directory. All the permission in folder and directory are setted to 777 so the other question are unusefull for me! am I missing somethink?

Comment: if you call `var_dump($my_file);` `var_dump($sharing_bet);` what is the output?

Comment: i putted var_dump($sharing_bet);
  file_put_contents($my_file, $sharing_bet);
  var_dump($my_file);  the first output is the string I need to load, the second nothing.

Comment: So `$my_file` is empty string? It does not make any sense if `$my_file` is empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I sorted Out:
the script is called from an android application and this was my java code to create a connection and POST some strings

```
 URL url = new URL(URL_STRING);
                HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                //conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.connect();

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                os.write(jsonBet.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                os.close();
```

I sorted adding this code below:

```
                if (200 <= conn.getResponseCode() && conn.getResponseCode() <= 299) {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    Log.i("response = " , br.readLine());
                } else {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
                    Log.i("response two = " , br.readLine());

                }
```

Seems like the connection goes down without setting a response code